# Getting error: follex.y:338:10: error：‘ZZ_DOTDOTDOT’ not yet declared in this scope when running TAMAR transfer learning

Tags: yacc, transfer-learning

When I ran the TAMAR, which is a system for transfer learning using MLNs by performing mapping and revision of previously learned MLNs.
I got errors from follex.y when I ran the

```
make transfered-learnstruct
```

The errors showed as follow:

```
    In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:205:10: error：‘ZZ_NUM’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_NUM;  
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:214:10: error：‘ZZ_NUM’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_NUM;
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:223:10: error：‘ZZ_NUM’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_NUM;
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:232:44: error：‘ZZ_CONSTANT’ not yet declared in this scope
   if (zzdomain->isConstant(yytext)) return ZZ_CONSTANT;
                                            ^
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:233:10: error：‘ZZ_STRING’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_STRING;
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:245:12: error：‘ZZ_TYPE’ not yet declared in this scope
     return ZZ_TYPE;
            ^
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:250:12: error：‘ZZ_PREDICATE’ not yet declared in this scope
     return ZZ_PREDICATE; 
            ^
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:255:12: error：‘ZZ_FUNCTION’ not yet declared in this scope
     return ZZ_FUNCTION;
            ^
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:260:12: error：‘ZZ_CONSTANT’ not yet declared in this scope
     return ZZ_CONSTANT;
            ^
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:263:10: error：‘ZZ_VARIABLE’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_VARIABLE;
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:329:10: error：‘ZZ_EQEQ’ not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_EQEQ;
          ^
In file included from /ut-alchemy/src/parser/fol.y:6:0:
/ut-alchemy/src/parser/follex.y:338:10: error：‘ZZ_DOTDOTDOT’not yet declared in this scope
   return ZZ_DOTDOTDOT;
```

The follex.y is

```
/* scanner for first-order language */

%{

#include "folhelper.h"

bool follexDbg = false; 
//bool follexDbg = true; 

%}


/* not scanning another file after current one */
%option noyywrap 

ZZ_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT ([/][/][^\r\n]*)
ZZ_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT ([/][*][^*]*[*]([*]|[^*][^*\/]*[*])*[/])

/* double ' and " to avoid string syntax highlighting in xemacs */
 /*ZZ_STRING  [""]([^""\\n\r] | ([\][ntbr\f''""]))*[""]*/
ZZ_STRING  ([""]([^""\\\n\r]|([\\][ntbr\f''""]))*[""])
ZZ_NOT ([!])
ZZ_OR  [ ]+[v][ \r\n]+
ZZ_AND [ ]+[\^][ \r\n]+
ZZ_IMPLY [=][>]
ZZ_EQUIV [<][=][>]
ZZ_EXIST  [Ee][Xx][Ii][Ss][Tt]
ZZ_FORALL [Ff][Oo][Rr][Aa][Ll][Ll]
ZZ_ASTERISK [*]
ZZ_PLUS [+]
ZZ_MINUS [-]
ZZ_MINUS_OR_PLUS [+-]
ZZ_QS [?]
ZZ_EQEQ  [=][=]
ZZ_EQ  [=]
ZZ_DOTDOTDOT [.][.][.]

ZZ_INCLUDE [#][i][n][c][l][u][d][e]

ZZ_DIGIT ([0-9]) 
/* double ' to avoid string syntax highlighting in xemacs */
ZZ_ID [a-zA-z_\-][a-zA-Z0-9_\-'']*

%%

"{" {
  if (follexDbg) printf("LBRACE: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


"}" {
  if (follexDbg) printf("RBRACE: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT} { 
  if (follexDbg) printf("SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT: %s\n", yytext);
  if (yytext[strlen(yytext)-1] == '\n' || yytext[strlen(yytext)-1] == '\r') 
    {
      ++zzline;
      zzcolumn = -1;
    } 
    else
      zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
}

{ZZ_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT} { 
  if (follexDbg) printf("MULTI_LINE_COMMENT: %s\n", yytext);
  int i=-1;
  while (yytext[++i] != '\0')
  {
    if (yytext[i] == '\n' || yytext[i] == '\r') 
    {
      ++zzline;
      zzcolumn = -1;
    } 
    else
      zzcolumn++;
  }
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext); 
}


{ZZ_INCLUDE} { 
  if (follexDbg) printf("INCLUDE: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_INCLUDE;
}


{ZZ_NOT} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("NOT: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_OR} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("OR: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add("v");
  return 'v';
}


{ZZ_AND} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("AND: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add("^");
  return '^';
}


{ZZ_IMPLY} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("IMPLY: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_IMPLY;
}


{ZZ_EQUIV} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("EQUIV: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_EQUIV;
}


{ZZ_EXIST} { 
  if (follexDbg) printf("EXIST: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_EXIST;
}


{ZZ_FORALL} { 
  if (follexDbg) printf("FORALL: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_FORALL;
}


{ZZ_ASTERISK} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("ASTERISK: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_PLUS} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("PLUS: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_MINUS} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("MINUS: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}

{ZZ_QS} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("QS: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_MINUS}?{ZZ_DIGIT}+ {
  if (follexDbg) printf("INTEGER: %s (%d)\n", yytext, atoi(yytext));
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_NUM;  
}


{ZZ_MINUS}?{ZZ_DIGIT}+"."{ZZ_DIGIT}* {
  if (follexDbg) printf("FLOAT: %s (%g)\n", yytext, atof(yytext));
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_NUM;
}


{ZZ_MINUS}?{ZZ_DIGIT}+"."?{ZZ_DIGIT}*"e"{ZZ_MINUS_OR_PLUS}?{ZZ_DIGIT}+ {
  if (follexDbg) printf("EXP_FLOAT: %s (%e)\n", yytext, atof(yytext));
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return ZZ_NUM;
}


{ZZ_STRING} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("STRING: %s \n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  if (zzdomain->isConstant(yytext)) return ZZ_CONSTANT;
  return ZZ_STRING;
}


{ZZ_ID} {
  //if (follexDbg) printf("IDENTIFIER: %s\n", yytext );
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  if (zzdomain->isType(yytext))
  { 
    if (follexDbg) printf("ZZ_TYPE: %s\n", yytext ); 
    return ZZ_TYPE;
  }
  if (zzdomain->isPredicate(yytext)) 
  { 
    if (follexDbg) printf("ZZ_PREDICATE: %s\n", yytext ); 
    return ZZ_PREDICATE; 
  }
  if (zzdomain->isFunction(yytext))  
  {  
    if (follexDbg) printf("ZZ_FUNCTION: %s\n", yytext ); 
    return ZZ_FUNCTION;
  }
  if (zzdomain->isConstant(yytext))
  {
    if (follexDbg) printf("ZZ_CONSTANT: %s\n", yytext ); 
    return ZZ_CONSTANT;
  }
  if (follexDbg) printf("ZZ_VARIABLE: %s\n", yytext ); 
  return ZZ_VARIABLE;
}


"\n"|"\r" {
  if (follexDbg) 
  {
    if (zzparseGroundPred) printf("AT: %c\n", '@');
    else                   printf("NEWLINE: %s", yytext);
  }
  ++zzline;
  zznumCharRead += 1;
  zzcolumn = -1;
  if (zzparseGroundPred) { 
    zzafterRtParen = false;
    zztokenList.add("@");
    return '@';
  }
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


"(" {
  if (follexDbg) printf("LEFT PAREN: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  if (zzparseGroundPred) zzafterRtParen = false;
  return yytext[0];
}


")" {
  if (follexDbg) printf("RIGHT PAREN: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  if (zzparseGroundPred) zzafterRtParen = true;
  return yytext[0];
}


"," {
  if (follexDbg) printf("COMMA: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


{ZZ_EQ} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("EQUAL: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add("=");
  return '=';
}


{ZZ_EQEQ} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("EQUALEQUAL: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add("==");
  return ZZ_EQEQ;
}


{ZZ_DOTDOTDOT} {
  if (follexDbg) printf("DOTDOTDOT: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add("...");
  return ZZ_DOTDOTDOT;
}


"@" {
  if (follexDbg) printf("AT: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


"." {
  if (follexDbg) printf("FULLSTOP: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];
}


[ \t]+ { /* eat up whitespace */
  if (follexDbg) 
  {
    if (zzparseGroundPred) printf("WS:\n");
  }
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);

  if (zzparseGroundPred && zzafterRtParen) { zztokenList.add("@"); return '@'; }
}


. {
    // commented out so as to allow fol.y to deal with the problem
  //printf("\nERROR: Unrecognized character. %s: ln %d, col %d: %s \n", 
  //       zzinFileName.c_str(), zzline, zzcolumn+1, yytext);
  //exit(-1);
  if (follexDbg) printf("Unrecognized character: %s\n", yytext);
  zzcolumn += strlen(yytext);
  zznumCharRead += strlen(yytext);
  zztokenList.add(yytext);
  return yytext[0];

}

<<EOF>> {

  if (zzparseGroundPred) 
  {
    if (zznumEofSeen == 0) 
    {
      zznumEofSeen++;
      if (follexDbg) printf("EOF returned as @:\n");
      zztokenList.add("@"); 
      return '@'; 
    }
    else
    {
      zzparseGroundPred = false;
      zzafterRtParen = false;
      zznumEofSeen = 0;
    }
  }

  if (zznumEofSeen==0)
  {
    ungetc(EOF, yyin);
    zznumEofSeen = 1;
    if (follexDbg) printf("EOF returned as \\n:\n");    
    zztokenList.add("\n");  // pretend that file ends with newline
    return '\n';
  }
  
  zznumEofSeen = 0;
  
  if (follexDbg) printf("EOF %s:\n", yytext);
  if (false) yyunput(1,NULL); //avoid compilation warning

  fclose(yyin);
  if (zzinStack.empty()) return 0;

  ZZFileState fileState = zzinStack.top();
  zzinFileName = fileState.inFileName_;
  zznumCharRead = fileState.numCharRead_;
  zzline = fileState.line_;
  zzcolumn = fileState.column_;
  zzinStack.pop();

  FILE* previn = fileState.file_;
  if (fseek(previn, zznumCharRead-1, SEEK_SET)!=0)
  {
    printf("\nERROR: In follex.y. Failed to seek to previous position in file "
           "%s, ln %d, col %d\n", zzinFileName.c_str(), zzline, zzcolumn+1);
    exit(-1);
  }
  yyrestart(previn);
  
}
%%
```

The fol.y is

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE int
#define YYDEBUG 1

#include "fol.h"
#include "follex.cpp"

  // 0: no output; 1,2: increasing order of verbosity
int folDbg = 0;
//int folDbg = 1;
//int folDbg = 2;

%}
     

/*************************** Declarations ***************************/
// the token 'error' is declared by Bison
%token ZZ_NUM
%token ZZ_DOTDOTDOT
%token ZZ_STRING
%token ZZ_EQEQ
%token ZZ_INCLUDE

%token ZZ_PREDICATE
%token ZZ_FUNCTION
%token ZZ_CONSTANT
%token ZZ_VARIABLE
%token ZZ_TYPE

%left '-' '+'

%token ZZ_FORALL
%token ZZ_EXIST
%left ZZ_EQUIV
%left ZZ_IMPLY
%left 'v'
%left '^'
%left '!'
%left '*' '/' '%'

%glr-parser
%expect 16
%error-verbose
%%
```

I searched a lot, but I cannot find solution. Could someone help me solve the problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to add the definition in the fol.h.

```
/* Tokens.  */
#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
   /* Put the tokens into the symbol table, so that GDB and other debuggers
      know about them.  */
   enum yytokentype {
     ZZ_NUM = 258,
     ZZ_DOTDOTDOT = 259,
     ZZ_STRING = 260,
     ZZ_EQEQ = 261,
     ZZ_INCLUDE = 262,
     ZZ_PREDICATE = 263,
     ZZ_FUNCTION = 264,
     ZZ_CONSTANT = 265,
     ZZ_VARIABLE = 266,
     ZZ_TYPE = 267,
     ZZ_FORALL = 268,
     ZZ_EXIST = 269,
     ZZ_EQUIV = 270,
     ZZ_IMPLY = 271
   };
#endif
/* Tokens.  */
#define ZZ_NUM 258
#define ZZ_DOTDOTDOT 259
#define ZZ_STRING 260
#define ZZ_EQEQ 261
#define ZZ_INCLUDE 262
#define ZZ_PREDICATE 263
#define ZZ_FUNCTION 264
#define ZZ_CONSTANT 265
#define ZZ_VARIABLE 266
#define ZZ_TYPE 267
#define ZZ_FORALL 268
#define ZZ_EXIST 269
#define ZZ_EQUIV 270
#define ZZ_IMPLY 271
```